# How to check category name available or not

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, categories

I have an input field and when users enter any text then that will check the category name is available or not which user entered.

**Js**

```
(function($) {  // ready handler
$(".universalSearchField").keypress(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { action: "universalSearchlist", keyword: $("#searchdata").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
           // $("#datafetch").html( data );
        }
    });
    });

    })(jQuery);
```

Function.php

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_universalSearchlist','universalSearch');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_universalSearchlist','universalSearch');
function universalSearch(){
$the_query = new WP_Query( array('category_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['universalSearchlist'] ), 'post_type' => 'post' ) );
    foreach ( $the_query->posts as $p ) {
    $categories = get_the_category($p->ID);
    if (!empty($categories) ) {
        echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name );   
    }
}
    
}
```

I am getting all the categories and I want when the user starts to enter the text box then start checking the category name is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use get_cat_ID('categoy name') https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_id/

```
<?php
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
if($category_id > 0){
echo 'category exists';
}else{
echo 'category NOT exists';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not working, I added you code inside foreach and  tried like this $category_id = get_cat_ID($p->ID);

Comment: It get the NAME not the ID as paramether

Answer (score 0):

Using `admin-ajax.php` and writing a custom handler is unnecessary, I would normally advise writing a REST API endpoint instead, but even that's unnecessary here.

Just ask the REST API for that category. If it returns the category, it exists, if it doesn't, then it doesn't.

E.g. `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/?slug=categoryname`

In javascript that might look like this:

```js
async function check_category_exists( slug ) {
    let response = await fetch( `https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/?slug=${slug}` );

    if (response.ok) { // if HTTP-status is 200-299
        // get the response body (the method explained below)
        let json = await response.json();
        return ( json.length > 0 );
    } else {
        throw new Exception( "HTTP-Error: " + response.status );
    }
}
```

Now we have an async JS function that fetches the term and if it's found returns `true`, and if it does not returns `false`. Remember these return promises, similar to the AJAX functions in jQuery and elsewhere. You would use it like this:

```js
check_category_exists( "test" ).then(
    ( result ) => {
        if ( result ) {
            console.log( "test exists" );
        } else {
            console.log( "it does not exist" );
        }
    }
).catch(
    error => console.log( "something went wrong" )
);
```

Be sure to change `example.com` to your site, or even better, make WP put the path to your REST API on the page so you can access it, and use the same code everywhere ( hint: ask this question on the site, easy to answer, lots of interesting things to know )

Alternatively, fetch the categories from the REST API via `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories` and store them in an array/list. Then you can use the array to list items in your search, and you can test if an item is in that array to see if it exists.

Comment: Why I am doing this because I am looking to search only for categories.

Comment: I don't understand can you rephrase/reword your comment a different way? The function is ***not*** for searching